# Magento 1 to Magento 2 Data Migration - migrate:data General error: 1419

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.2, mysql-triggers

I've got a problem with migrating data from Magento 1.9.4.2 to Magento 2.3.2 in migrate:data.

In step: Stage I've got General error 1419 and I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of privileges. You can fix this issue by setting the value of the log_bin_trust_function_creators parameter as 1.

You can execute below SQL:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Where I should use this code?

Comment: You can use this in your PHPMyAdmin section.

Comment: Hi, log_bin_trust_function_creators was't set. Place 1 solved problem. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear. Cheers!!!